# Applying function within a loop to a list of dataframes

Tags: list, function, loops, nested, lapply

I am trying to run a loop containing a function over a list of dataframes. My data is structured as follows:

models <-

| var1 | var2 | var3 | model |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "temp" | "pres" | "dis" |
| 2 | "sal" | "temp" | "gage" |
| 3 | "dis" | "temp" | "gage" |
| 4 | "pres" | "temp" | "gage" |
| 5 | "sal" | "dis" | "gage" |
| 6 | "sal" | "temp" | "pres" |

data <-

| y | "temp" | "pres" | "dis" | "sal" | "gage" | "Delay" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 15.5 | 0.3 | 1500 | 0.01 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 15.6 | 0.1 | 1700 | 0.03 | 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 15.7 | 0.0 | 1450 | 0.01 | 5 | 0 |
| 4 | 15.9 | 0.2 | 1560 | 0.02 | 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 15.5 | 0.3 | 1500 | 0.01 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 15.6 | 0.1 | 1700 | 0.03 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 15.7 | 0.0 | 1450 | 0.01 | 5 | 1 |
| 4 | 15.9 | 0.2 | 1560 | 0.02 | 4 | 1 |

The function selects the columns from "data" that match the string within the dataframe "models" for each row, i, of "models", then runs each model and returns summary statistics.

```
library(tidyverse)
runningmodels <- function(df){
  var1 <- models[[i,1]] #selects the variable
  var2 <- models[[i,2]]
  var3 <- models[[i,3]]
  cols <- c("y",var1, var2, var3, "Delay") #makes a list of the variable strings
  df <- data %>% select(cols) #selects columns in data that match with cols
  df <- df %>% rename(
    y=1,
    x1=2,
    x2=3,
    x3=4) #renames the columns to a dummy variable so I can apply this across multiple models
  lm <- lm(y ~ x1*x2*x3, data=df) #running the model
  l <- as.list(summary(lm)) #getting summary data
  dat <- tibble(model=models[[i,4]], r2=l$r.squared, Delay=df[[1,5]]) #pasting what model has been run based on the models dataframe and pasting what delay was used
  return(dat)
}
```

This function (running models) is run for each line in "models" using the following loop:

```
models_summary <- list()
for(i in 1:nrow(models)){
  tryCatch({
    models_summary[[i]] <- runningmodels(models)}, error=function(e){cat("Error")})
}
models_summary <- do.call("rbind",models_summary)
```

I am able to run the loop containing the runningmodels function across my dataset, however I want to do so separately for each Delay. I can successfully do so when I manually parse out each delay into its own dataframe (as follows):

```
data1 <- data %>% filter(Delay == 0) 
data2 <- data %>% filter(Delay == 1)
```

And running the loop on each dataframe (data1, data2). However, my actual dataset has 6 lists, so this is quite annoying and I'd like to avoid.

I have also tried incorporating lapply, which will run model-1 for each Delay list but won't iterate through the entire loop for all models after splitting my data:

```
data_split \<- split(data, data$Delay)
x <- lapply(data_split, runningmodels) ##this produces just the results of model-1 for each delay
```

Closest I've gotten is creating a second function with the loop, but this results in NULL output lists.

```
modelruns <- function(x) {
  for(i in 1:nrow(models)) { 
    tryCatch({
      df <- runningmodels(models)
      models_summary[[i]] <- df
    }, error=function(e){cat("ERROR")})
  }#loop to repeat resampling n times
}
models_all <- lapply(data_split, modelruns)
```

I suspect the way I'm ordering my loop + function + list is not correct, and I've tried other iterations of a single function, a single loop, multiple of each, etc. to no avail. Any suggestions?

Fake data:

```
models <- tibble(var1 = c("temp","sal","dis","pres","sal","sal"),
                 var2 = c("pres","temp","temp","temp","dis","temp"),
                 var3 = c("dis","gage","gage","gage","gage","pres"),
                 model = c("model-1","model-2","model-3","model-4","model-5","model-6"))
data <- tibble(y = rep(c(5,1,2,4,8,6,2,3),times=10),
               temp = rep(c(15.5, 15.6, 15.7, 15.8, 15.9, 16.0, 16.1, 16.2),times=10),
               pres = rep(c(0.3,0.1,0.0,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7),times=10),
               dis = rep(c(1500,1810,1800,1560,1540,1700,1450,1510),times=10),
               sal = rep(c(0.01,0.03,0.02,0.04,0.07,0.06,0.00,0.08),times=10),
               gage = rep(c(1,2,5,3,4,8,-3,-2),times=10),
               Delay = rep(c(0:1),each=40))
```